# sp_execute_external_script invoking a R script file

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I have a long R-script file and I would like to use SQL Server R Services, reading about its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt591996.aspx), I have not seen any example of using: `sp_execute_external_script` that allows loading an R-script file. All examples are intended to use simple r-computation embedded in a SQL sentences, such as the following example:

```
DROP PROC IF EXISTS get_iris_dataset;  
go  
CREATE PROC get_iris_dataset  
AS  
BEGIN  
EXEC   sp_execute_external_script  
   @language = N'R'  
 , @script = N'iris_data <- iris;'  
 , @input_data_1 = N''  
 , @output_data_1_name = N'iris_data'  
 WITH RESULT SETS (("Sepal.Length" float not null,   
       "Sepal.Width" float not null,  
    "Petal.Length" float not null,   
    "Petal.Width" float not null, "Species" varchar(100)));  
END;  
go
```

I would need in some way to use the r-sentence `source("fileName")` for executing the r-sentences.

**Note**: I am trying to use an SQL Server just because a better machine performance than my personal computer.

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: Are the R script files you are trying to source saved on the SQL Server machine? If so, you should be able to source then just like in R assuming there is read access to them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly possible to use `source("filename")` you execute an R script.
The R script should be located somewhere SQL Server has access to it.
For instance: `source("C:/Rscripts/script.R")`. Note that SQL Server has no access to your My Documents folder...

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'R'
,@script = N'
source("C:/Rscripts/script.R");'
,@input_data_1 = N''  
,@output_data_1_name = N'iris_data'  
WITH RESULT SETS (("Sepal.Length" float not null,   
 "Sepal.Width" float not null,  
 "Petal.Length" float not null,   
 "Petal.Width" float not null, "Species" varchar(100)));
```